# hilios javascript countdown timer finish event worn initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, countdown

Im using this [javascript countdown plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html) and I want to detect the finish date, here's my set up and so far what i've tried.

```
$('#countdown').countdown('2015/11/12', function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('<div id="countdown_container"><div class="countdown_wrap weeks">%w weeks</div><div class="countdown_wrap days">%d days</div><div class="countdown_wrap hours">%H:%M:%S</div>'));
}).on('finish.countdown', function(event){
    alert("the event is finish");
});
```

but seems doesn't work, any ideas, help please?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the 'legacy approach' and as [the documentation](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#introduction) says:

> With the legacy approach you will need to handle all events in a
>   single callback (update, finish or stop) through the event.type
>   property

You should use the newer method:

```
$('#countdown').countdown('2015/11/12')
    .on('update.countdown', function(e) {
        $(this).html(e.strftime('<div id="countdown_container"><div class="countdown_wrap weeks">%w weeks</div><div class="countdown_wrap days">%d days</div><div class="countdown_wrap hours">%H:%M:%S</div>'));
    })
    .on('finish.countdown', function(e) {
        alert("the event is finish");
    });
```

Or if you still want to use the older syntax:

```
$('#countdown').countdown('2015/11/12', function(event) {
    if (event.type === 'update.countdown') {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('<div id="countdown_container"><div class="countdown_wrap weeks">%w weeks</div><div class="countdown_wrap days">%d days</div><div class="countdown_wrap hours">%H:%M:%S</div>'));
    } else if (event.type === 'finish.countdown') {
        alert("the event is finish");
    });
```